# Extreme slowness in Visual Studio 2010's Exceptions Dialog - how to prevent?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

Recently Visual Studio's Exception Dialog load-up is more infuriatingly slow than usual - taking as much as 1 minute (!) to show up.

Are there any tried-and-true methods to fix this?

I've already tried unchecking "Microsoft Symbol Server" checkbox under Options/Debugging, and changing the symbols directory to an empty folder, but that didn't help.

Comment: Although it won't solve your problem in the short term, consider installing PerfWatson to report this slow dialog to Microsoft: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa85b17d-3df2-49b1-bee6-71527ffef441.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never been a particularly quick dialog, there's a ton of info buried in it, but a minute is outrageous.  The symbol server settings does not affect this dialog, that can't be it.  Do watch out for using the Add option, maybe used in a previous project with an exception type that was defined in an assembly that's not there anymore.  Maybe on a network share, long delays like that are almost always network timeouts.

Get better insight in what's cranking away during this minute with SysInterals' ProcMon utility.

Comment: @Omer: for future reference, what was the cause of the slowdown?

Comment: ProcMon helped me discover that there was a malicious injected DLL that my antivirus did not detect, doing its busywork inside devenv.exe while i'm waiting for the Exceptions Dialog.

Comment: I'm finding it's the 565K registry keys devenv scans on my box when opening the dialog. I wish it cached these for subsequent openings :-(